# Not able to use camera resource after updating camera: ^0.10.0 takepicture() function does not working

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-dependencies

I'm not able to use cameraControllers.takePicture after updating the CAMERA version from 0.5.8+17 to 0.10.0 in pubspec.yaml

I've attached last code.
Please correct me where I'm wrong

```
try {
  final p = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final name = DateTime.now();
  final path = "${p.path}/$name.png";


  await cameraController.takePicture(path).then((value) {
    if (valuetype == '1') {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddProfile(
                    imgPath: path,
                    fileName: "$name.png",
                    imagetype: "1",
                  )));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MyApp(
                    imgPath: path,
                    fileName: "$name.png",
                  ))).then((erg) {
        if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        } else {
          SystemNavigator.pop();
        }
      });
    }
    print(imgPath + 'image path');
  });



} catch (e) {
  showCameraException(e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
  onCapture(context) async {
    try {
      File imageFile;
      // final p = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      XFile xFile = await cameraController.takePicture();
      if (xFile != null) {
        imageFile = File(xFile.path);
      }
      final name = DateTime.now();
      // final path = "${imageFile.path}/$name.png";

      if (imageFile != null && imageFile.existsSync()) {
        if (valuetype == '1') {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AddProfile(
                            imgPath: imageFile.path,
                            fileName: "$name.png",
                            imagetype: "1",
                          )));
            } else {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MyApp(
                            imgPath: imageFile.path,
                            fileName: "$name.png",
                          ))).then((erg) {
                if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                } else {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                }
              });
            }
            print(imgPath + 'image path');
      } else {
        print('Image file does not exist');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showCameraException(e);
    }
  }
```

this is worked for me